# Compare strings in C using getchar

Tags: c, string, char, comparison, buffer

I know this has been asked before and I've read through the answers.  I also know that my code isn't great as I'm still learning C.  I'm trying, without any luck, to compare a user entered char with a char in an if statement.  All and any advice is appreciated.  Also, I'm aware of buffer issues though just trying to get the comparison to work first.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void){

//int n;
//const char *F = "F";
//float temp;
//float converted;

printf("Would you like to enter Fahrenheit or Celcius? Please type F or C: ");
//scanf("%c", &a);
char input = getchar(); //This will get a single Char from the user and keep it as a char

printf("%c\n", input);

//n = strcmp(input, F);

if(input == "C") {  

        printf("Please enter the temp you would like to convert to Fahrenheit: ");
        scanf("%f", &temp);
        converted = temp * 9/5 +32;

        printf("You entered %2f Celcius and that equals %2f Fahrenheit\n", temp, converted);

}else if(strcmp(input, "f") == 0) || (strcmp(input, "F") == 0){

        printf("Please enter the temp you would like to convert to Celcius: ");
        scanf("%f", &temp);

  }else{

        printf("You didn't enter F or C");

   }



}
```

Comment: Does the compiler yell out a warning here: `if(input == "C")`? `"C"` and `'C'` are not the same.

Comment: AHHHHHHHHHHHHH HA!!!  I had used double quotes instead of single quotes!!!!  Thank you!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 3):

```
int strcmp ( const char * str1, const char * str2 );
```

`strcmp` takes two `string` variables.

but your `input` variable is a `char`. So use `if(input == 'C')` and `if(input == 'F')`

Comment: The problem was I was using double quotes.  Thank you for responding!!!!  I appreciate your feedback.

Answer (score 2):

You are comparing characters so it should be `input=='C'`.
By the way don't forget to put dummy `getchar()` so that the `\n` doesn't come into the input character.

Also you are using `char input` in `strcmp()`. 
You have not declared `temp` or `converted`.
Note: In `C` you can't compare strings by using `==`.

### Corrected code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void){

//int n;
//const char *F = "F";
float temp;
float converted;

printf("Would you like to enter Fahrenheit or Celcius? Please type F or C: ");
//scanf("%c", &a);
char input[10];// = getchar(); //This will get a single Char from the user and keep it as a char
scanf("%s",input);
printf("%s\n", input);

//n = strcmp(input, F);

if(strcmp(input,"C")==0) {  

        printf("Please enter the temp you would like to convert to Fahrenheit: ");
        scanf("%f", &temp);
        converted = temp * 9/5 +32;

        printf("You entered %2f Celcius and that equals %2f Fahrenheit\n", temp, converted);

}else if((strcmp(input, "f") == 0) || (strcmp(input, "F") == 0)){

        printf("Please enter the temp you would like to convert to Celcius: ");
        scanf("%f", &temp);

  }else{

        printf("You didn't enter F or C");

   }



}
```